# Selenium: Loop webdrivers (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I want to run multiple chrome instances with selenium. I tried to loop the webdrivers but selenium keeps shutting the instances down.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


user = str(input("Do you want to run this program? "))
amount = 0

if user == "yes":
    amount = int(input("How many instances do you want to run? "))
    for w in range(1, amount+1):
        webdriver.Chrome("path of my driver")
elif user == "no":
    print("Program is closing...")
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

The weird thing is that the instances wont close if i write them without a loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver


user = str(input("Do you want to run this program? "))

if user == "yes":
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome("path of driver")
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome("path of driver")
    driver3 = webdriver.Chrome("path of driver")
    driver4 = webdriver.Chrome("path of driver")
    driver5 = webdriver.Chrome("path of driver")
elif user == "no":
    print("Program is closing...")
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Use `driver.close()` to close the current browser window having focus, else`driver.quit()` to quit the whole browser session along with all the associated browser windows, tabs, and pop-ups.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the instances when you write it without a loop then do the following.

> driver.close() - It closes the the browser window on which the focus
>   is set.
>
> driver.quit() – It basically calls driver.dispose method which in turn
>   closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session
>   gracefully.

You should use driver.quit whenever you want to end the program. It will close all opened browser window and terminates the WebDriver session.

Consider writing your loop example in the following way, this will handle shutting the instances much better.

Using either `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` module to trigger the task in parallel (near parallel).

**Multithreading example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import time


def test_logic():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = 'https://www.google.co.in'
    driver.get(url)
    # Implement your test logic
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

N = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
thread_list = list()

# Start test
for i in range(N):
    t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print t.name + ' started!'
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all thre<ads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print 'Test completed!'
```

Here, spawning 5 browsers to run test cases at one time. Instead of implementing the test logic I have put sleep time of 2 seconds for the purpose of demonstration. The code will fire up 5 firefox browsers (tested with python 2.7), open google and wait for 2 seconds before quitting.

Logs:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/swadchan/Documents/TestPyCharm/stackoverflow/so49617485.py
Test 0 started!
Test 1 started!
Test 2 started!
Test 3 started!
Test 4 started!
Test completed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was exactly the solution for my problem.